# Asp.net MVC 5 & Identity / Restricting Data By User / IdentityXXX vs AspNetXXX tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm new to MVC 5 and trying to get my head around the new Identity membership system, so forgive my newbie/ignorance on the subject.

My goal... Restrict data sent back to the user to make sure it's the user's data.  I am using Entity Framework and have a set of APIs exposing data for a SPA app.  On top of adding [Authorize] to the APIs, I need to (of course) also make sure the data getting retrieved is only the user's data, e.g. if I have a travel site, I only want to return that user's reservations not all in the system.

What I have done so far... I started a new MVC project so I can use the Identity membership.  Next, I added my existing model and data layers that contain my model for the reservation system.  Success... all working as it should.  In the database, I see all of my travel site tables, a set of AspnetUser tables and a set of Identity tables. Next up, link the reservation entities to the users.

So, in my model, I create links to what I think is going to be the AspNetUsers entities/tables (as this is where both external and regular users are stored --- for me only external users, fb/google/etc, are stored in the Identity tables) in several of my classes:

```
public class Reservation() {

... properties ...      

// Add FK to link reservation to user               
[ForeignKey("User")]
public string UserId { get; set; }
public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

}
```

... and, I'm using the standard IdentityModel.cs file...

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
```

... but, instead, it's linking to the Identity tables.  So, this does not work...

```
public IQueryable<Reservation> Reservations()
{       
        var sUserId = getUserId();  // fctn below       
        _repository.Reservations.Where(r => r.UserId == sUserId); 
}
```

This foreign key is linked to the IdentityUser table, not the AspnetUser table.  If the user is a locally registered user, not one using an external login (fb/google/etc), the system only adds the user in the AspnetUser table, not the IdentityUser table.  This means I can't just add the user's Id to the data table because the foreign key isn't valid as the user's Id isn't in the IdentityUser table.  I quickly added this function for testing in my API controller for testing:

```
private string getUserId() {
    UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
    if (User.Identity.GetUserId() != null)
    {
        return User.Identity.GetUserId();
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

So, my question is what should I be doing here to achieve my desired result of associating data to users?  Should the foreign key/table be to something different?  Am I taking an incorrect approach in adding foreign key relationships back to the user tables?